# Change value in config without opening

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell

Is it possible to change/uncomment value in linux configs without opening and go to line?

**Example:** In php.ini we had `expose_php = On` and we want turn it off:

```
$: magic_cmd "expose_php = Off"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the stream editor:

```
  sed -ie 's/expose_php = On/expose_php = Off/' php.ini
```

Comment: Worth noting from the `sed` man page:
-i extension
Edit files in-place, saving backups with the specified extension.
If a zero-length extension is given, no backup will be saved.  It
is not recommended to give a zero-length extension when in-place
editing files, as you risk corruption or partial content in situ-
ations where disk space is exhausted, etc.